# Nested slider for horizontal AND vertical movement together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, touch

I want to understand if there's a jQuery or JavaScript package out there that allows both horizontal and vertical sliding of images/data at the same time in one nested slider?

I'm having trouble finding a package that allows this to work effectively.

It needs to have buttons to go up, down, left and right as well as the ability to slide using finger gesture when used with touch screen (optional). Also, when on slide 1c for example, when next is selected to go to slide 2a not 2c. Any help or advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: We can't do your research for you buddy. Try Google. Then try building or modifying one yourself. Then you have a specific challenge, we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

check out ankkit.com. its a portfolio of a friend of mine. he has done what you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) Plugin? I think this is what you are looking for.